# How do I make IIS hosted asmx webservice browser based instead of browsing through inetmgr

Tags: c#, iis

I have developed an asmx web service in C#. I have also hosted this on IIS. Just a quick question about the debugging. Do I have to always right click and select browse under Context View.

Or can I open up a browser window and navigate to the asmx url on localhost. If not how do I make it work only with browser action and not always inetmgr.

Comment: Did you try it? And what does debugging have to do with it?

Comment: @Crowcoder I haven't tried it. I'm thinking out of the box. Can you please confirm if possible.

Comment: I don't understand why you would ask this question on SO and wait hours for an answer when all you have to do paste the url into a browser and see what happens. Yes, you can use a browser, that is all the "browse" command from IIS does.

Comment: @Crowcoder so can I go straight to my browser after I start my PC and type in the URL?

Comment: If your service responds to a GET and doesn't require anything you can't set from your browser (like headers) then yes you can, that is exactly what is happening when you do it from IIS manager.

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t fully get your point. What we have to do might add a URL shortcut to the browser favorites.
Besides, to debug the ASMX file(XML web service) quickly, IIS Express that integrated into VS is enough. Just add a breakpoint to the web method then Press F5 in VS, and then click the IIS Express icon in the left bottom.
[image]
Moreover, in the common property page of the solution, tick the Current Selection option of the startup project. this will open the `Web.asmx` file automatically when debugging. it is also a quick shortcut for debugging.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Quan I want to just switch on my PC and go straight to my favorite browser and view the asmx startup page.

Comment: Host the web service in the IIS and click the website index page in the binding list, then add a shortcut to the webservice page. Do this solve your problem?